# Write to stdout without creating a buffer

Tags: go

Inside a loop I do some calculations and then I want to print a string value from a byte array, once the loop is done print a new line.

Using `fmt.Print` will allocate a buffer, but all I want to do is print the character to stdout. Is there a way to do that?

```
for i, i < size; i++ {
    b = a[i] + i * 10
    fmt.Print(string((b)))
}
fmt.Println()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this by simply writing to the [`os.Stdout`](https://godoc.org/os#pkg-variables) file:

```
var buff [1]byte
for i, i < size; i++ {
    b = a[i] + i * 10
    buff[0] = b
    os.Stdout.Write(buff[:])
}
buff[0] = '\n'
os.Stdout.Write(buff[:])
```

Comment: thx, `b` is a byte not an integer, and I can't use io.WriteString, for some reason converting b to string doesn't print anything

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmt.Printf` instead of your `fmt.Print(string((b)))` like so:

```
 fmt.Printf("%c", b)
```

Comment: `Printf` uses the struct `pp` internally. It does use a pool of these, but it still will allocate if needed. https://golang.org/src/fmt/print.go?s=5096:5159#L179